# dropdown select box option not working in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, angularjs

when i select the language english in firefox then alert come but when i

select it in chrome then alert not display.i don't know what is wrong there.

below is the code of select box:

```
<select name="setlanguage" id="setlanguage" class="language" data-ng-model="setlanguage">

<option  onclick="alert();"><span>English</span></option>

<option><span>French</span></option>

</select>
```

Comment: you set the event handler on the `select` rather than individual `option`

Comment: instead of option you can use onchange  event handler for selectbox.

Comment: Options don't consistently fire mouse events in all browsers, so do as mentioned above, use the `change` event on the select element

Comment: its working in chrome any kind of event not generating in select box on chrome.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP or CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use onchange on the select tag--

```
<select name="setlanguage" id="setlanguage" class="language" onchange="alert('worked')" data-ng-model="setlanguage">
     <option>English</option>
     <option>French</option>
</select>
```

Comment: hello sheetal it works fine but i don't know why onclick event not arise in chrome can you please tell me.

Comment: there are some browsers that don't support onclick on options of select tag and chrome is one of them